# Hi All, I am new to shell scripting and I am getting syntax error but not sure where it's incorrect

Tags: shell, unix

I have a scenario that a json file should be created only when text file is available otherwise json file shouldn't be created.

```
File = " ABC.txt"
If [ -f $File]; then
 echo "file exist"
 json_data=$(cat <<EOF
 {
    "Data_format": "txt",
    "Dataset_name": "abc.txt",
    "No_of_file": "1",
    "Header" :true
    "delimeter": ",",
    "Code_page": "UTF-8",
    
  }
  EOF
  )
 echo "$json_data";

 echo "$json_data" > incident.json

Else
 "Text file doesn't exist"
fi
```

Above code is throwing error as -
Unexpected EOF while looking for matching ') '
Syntax error unexpected end of file

Can someone help is resolving the error

Comment: Start small and fix the obvious syntax errors first. What happens if you remove the `json_data=$(...)` expression? Does the code run without errors? Does it behave as expected?

Comment: Please copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix any errors that it flags. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` or which every shell you are using as the firrst line of code. If that doesn't solve your problem, then paste your corrected code into your question and add a note "Validated by ShellCheck" (or similar). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different issues:

- It is nice to start with `#!/bin/bash` and paste into https://www.shellcheck.net/
- When assigning something to a var, do not add spaces around `=`.
- Are you sure your file  `ABC.txt` starts with a space?
- Case sensitive: write if-then-else in lowercase
- Don't put spaces before `END` (indenting is good, but not for a here-document)
- `echo` before `"Text file doesn't exist"`

Together:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=" ABC.txt"
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
  echo "file exist"
  json_data=$(cat <<EOF
  {
    "Data_format": "txt",
    "Dataset_name": "abc.txt",
    "No_of_file": "1",
    "Header" :true
    "delimeter": ",",
    "Code_page": "UTF-8",
    
  }
EOF
  )
 echo "$json_data"
 echo "$json_data" > incident.json
else
 echo "Text file doesn't exist"
fi
```